# How should a developer setup Azure for a customer?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, windows-live-id, microsoft-account

I don't want ShortTermDeveloper@hotmail.com to be the admin of my Azure account. I also don't want to share the Admin@MyBusiness.com password with a bunch of developers. What I want (I think) is what we're used to - admin account(s) and sub accounts, even groups.

What's the best way to handle user management for an Azure account for a business?

What variables matter?

- If I have a domain? Do I have to have one?
- Some special subscription level? What is it called?

Thanks

Comment: This should be posted on ServerFault, or via billing support, since it's not a programming-related question. Also, when it comes to setting up for a business, there are several options that you can explore, depending on your company's size, whether you're a startup, etc.

Comment: This is a developer question. There is little guidance here, especially for developers wanting to build an Azure solution and hand it off to their customers. Developers aren't going to go to ServerFault. Take it from me, a developer, ... ever. Don't put it here and you might as well tell developers to guess (as they are doing now).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout the "Sign up for Windows Azure as an organization" page on windowsazure.com: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sign-up-organization/

Quoting from the site:

> "Once this tenant has been created, an admin can then issue
>   organizational accounts to each of its employees/students and assign
>   licenses to those accounts based on which cloud service subscriptions
>   they need access to, such as Windows Azure."

Sounds like what you need!

Answer (score 5):

I have worked on a number of client engagements using Azure and a good practice is to have the client setup the subscription. The Pay-As-You-Go option is an excellent starting point as there is no commitment and free trial periods apply in certain scenarios.

The client then adds developer accounts to the subscription to perform the actual work. The client maintains billing control and ownership of the subscriptions. The client simply removes their accounts from the Subscription when the developers / consultants complete scoped work items.